# amsmath's multline causes "Missing $ inserted" error

Tags: amsmath, multline

I use the `multline` feature from `amsmath` to display an equation that spreads acroos multiple rows. I tried to do that like this:

```
\begin{multline}
    \label{eq:volume_boundaries}
    \int\limits_S \Gamma\nabla\phi\cdot\mathbf{n}\d{S} =
    \int\limits_{S_\text{n}} (\Gamma\nabla\phi\cdot\mathbf{n})_\text{n}\d{S_\text{n}} 
    +\int\limits_{S_\text{e}} (\Gamma\nabla\phi\cdot\mathbf{n})_\text{e}\d{S_\text{e}}\\
    +\int\limits_{S_\text{s}} (\Gamma\nabla\phi\cdot\mathbf{n})_\text{s}\d{S_\text{s}}
    +\int\limits_{S_\text{w}} (\Gamma\nabla\phi\cdot\mathbf{n})_\text{w}\d{S_\text{w}}
\end{multline}
```

However this leads to the error message `Missing $ inserted. \end{multline}`. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Please tell us how or where the `\d` macro is defined. (Usually, it's a text-mode-only macro.)

Comment: Unrelated, never use `\text` like that, this is not what that macro is for. It does not do what you think

Comment: Should I use `\mathrm` instead?

Comment: Without the `\limits` the limits are written to the right of the integral sign, with `\limits` they are below and above them, I thought.

Comment: @Axel: regarding `\limits`, you should try and see. Standard setup has `\int` in display mode math already working in the way you want. If you loaded a package that changes this default, chances are the package also has an option to undo it.

Comment: @daleif: I am not sure I agree. If the `n`, `e`, `s`, and `w` are considered as text labels for the directions, why is it wrong? If they were spelled out I would consider `$S_\text{north}$` the correct formatting.

Comment: @Axel if you're writing in English, yes I would use mathrm and I would use `_{...} ` it is a bit of a floke that this can be used with braces so no a good idea to depen on it.

Comment: @WillieWong a text label should always be upright, but that is not what `\text` does. Try `\textit{test $\text{test}$} `. The construction you use for something like this formatting should not depend on the context. Therefore `\text` is wring here. Generally `\text` is for textual comments in displayed math, not textual indices, they are not the same thing.

Comment: As @Mico said: Your problem is most likely that you are trying to use the `\d` command to set an upright letter `d` in math mode (something like `\mathrm{d}`), perhaps with some spacing, But you likely forgot to load the package that actually (re)defines the command. By default `\d` is not a math-mode macro. (Also, in some packages I've seen this defined as `\D` and not `\d`...)

Comment: @daleif: what about `\textrm` then instead of `\mathrm`?

Comment: @WillieWong that would be fine or textup. In the idea world the letters would be the same in text and math. But if you need to write non-ascii letters you need to use textup or textnormal, so in Danish the radius of a lake would be `R_{\textup{sø}} ` because ø is not allowed in math mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of the problem you've encountered is that you're trying to use a text-mode-only command -- `\d` -- in math mode.

Rather than undefine and then redefine `\d` suitably, I think it's better to create a macro with a new name -- say, `\diff` -- to denote the "differential operator". E.g.,

```
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
```

Observe that this command does *not* take an argument. Thus, I would encourage you to just write `\diff S`, not `\diff{S}`, as the latter might create the (misleading and inappropriate) impression that `\diff` is a macro that takes an argument.

I would also replace with all instances of `\int\limits` with just `\int`, as I can't see a (typographic) justification for elongating the equation in the vertical direction.

Finally, I think the equation is easier to read if you used an `\equation`/`aligned` combination instead of a `multline` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}} % don't re-purpose the existing '\d' macro
\newcommand{\gnpn}{\Gamma\nabla\mkern-2mu \phi\cdot\mathbf{n}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:volume_boundaries}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\int_S \gnpn \diff S 
    &=      \int_{S_\mathrm{n}}\!  (\gnpn)_{\mathrm{n}}\diff S_{\mathrm{n}} 
           +\int_{S_\mathrm{e}}\!  (\gnpn)_{\mathrm{e}}\diff S_{\mathrm{e}}\\
    &\quad +\int_{S_\mathrm{s}}\!  (\gnpn)_{\mathrm{s}}\diff S_{\mathrm{s}}
           +\int_{S_\mathrm{w}}\!\!(\gnpn)_{\mathrm{w}}\diff S_{\mathrm{w}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to be picky, `\diff{S}` (in math mode) is completely equivalent to `\diff S`, because TeX strips off the braces when the subformula consists of a single atom.

Comment: @egreg - I know that too. :-) My point was not so much about the appearance of the output than about not creating a misleading impression that `\diff` is a macro that takes an argument. I will update my answer to clarify this.

Comment: I had already upvoted, of course.